# Can't Find The Fix For Launch Screen (Splash Image) Transition

Tags: ios, xcode, launch

I've spent hours trying to figure out what I would think is something very easy to do. I'm using the default Launch Image and I want it to be showing until my main menu transitions onto the screen. the problem is it fades to black and it doesn't seem to be changeable despite all the research and copy/paste of code. There is just so many errors and not enough detail in the answers.

The whole reason i want this to not fade is because my main menu enters through transition from the top of screen and is like an "extension" from the launch image, as if the main menu is pushing down my launch image until it fills the whole screen.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm still a beginner in Xcode programming so detail would be great. Please post code and any variables or anything that need to be added for it to work.

THANKS!

Comment: Can you add some relevant code? It could be helpful...

Comment: Well that's the thing, i'm looking for the code, I dont have any code. And I think it depends on what I use to make this happen...

Comment: I think like @Siju said though, I have to create a UIImageView or something. I just dont know how and where. thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can't do any animation with the launch image. Solution for your problem is you can keep a view showing the launch image after the launch screen appears when app opens. And you can do any animation with that view and your main menu.

Comment: Well yes I have seen a post on this and that makes sense I just have no idea of the code, and the code I have copy/pasted just keeps giving me errors. But are you telling me that a transition is like an animation then? I'm just wanting a smooth transition from the splash to the main menu screen. And if i did have an identical image behind the launch, how would I make it not fade? Cause wouldn't the launch image still be fading like it is? Code and details on how to do this would be appreciated man, thanks.